# How do I switch views in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular, and have read all the tutorials, but am just starting out building my own app, so I am at the steep bit of the learning curve!

I am building a questionnaire. I would like to show one question at a time, along with occasional optional content on each screen (depending on the answers given to the questions).

My question is about the cleanest way to structure this in my controller.

Currently my HTML looks like this:

```
<div ng-show="showIntro"> <!-- Intro, shown by default -->
  Intro
  <button ng-click="nextIntro">Next</button>
</div>

<div ng-show="showQ1"> <!-- Question 1, shown after the user clicks Next -->
  Question 1

<label class="checkbox-inline"> <!-- Radio buttons for user response -->
  <input type="radio" name="ast-adh-p1-q1" ng-model="q1aVal" 
   ng-change='answerQ1(q1aVal)' value="yes"> Yes
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="ast-adh-p1-q1" ng-model="value" 
  ng-change='answerQ1(value)' value="no"> No
</label>

 <div ng-show="showQ1extra"> <!-- Shown if user answers yes to question 1 -->
   some extra content if the user answers yes to question 1 here
 </div>

 <button ng-click="nextQ1">Next</button>

</div>

<div ng-show="showQ2"> <!-- Question 2, shown after completing question 1 -->
  Question 2 ...
</div>
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
    $scope.showIntro = true;
    $scope.showQ1 = false;
    $scope.showQ1extra = false;
    $scope.showQ2 = false;

    $scope.nextIntro = function() {
      $scope.showIntro = false;
      $scope.showQ1 = true;
    }

    $scope.answerQ1 = function(q1aVal) {
      $scope.showQ1extra = (q1aVal === 'yes') ? true : false;
    }

    $scope.nextQ1 = function() {
      $scope.showQ1 = false;
      $scope.showQ1extra = false;
      $scope.showQ2 = true;
    }
```

It works, but is inelegant and not scalable. Is there a more sensible, Angular way to do it?

My own feeling is that there should be a `$scope.activeSection` parameter, that is a number, and that is initially set to 0. Then `showIntro` should return `$scope.activeSection === 0`, etc, and there should be a single `Next` button that increments `activeSection` by 1 each time. Does that sound like an Angular-friendly way of doing things?

Update: Here is a plunker with sample code: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ursyhc7YJYbJS5OCGYEr?p=preview

Comment: create a live demo with some sample data in plunker or jsfiddle.net

Comment: I think isse is you aren't using data array yet and trying to build controller from data array structure. You would only have one section of html for any question

Comment: Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ursyhc7YJYbJS5OCGYEr?p=preview

Comment: take a look at this  http://plnkr.co/edit/GIpWLlURGroFwzOvLtFJ?p=preview. Start with models, then don't need a lot of repetitive html.

Comment: @charlietfl - that is a better solution, if you want to submit it, I will accept it...

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this with a quite small amount of code using [the "ngSwitch" directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch).

HTML:

```
<div ng-switch="step">
    <div ng-switch-when="1">
        <p>This is step 1</p>
        <button ng-click="setStep(2)" class="btn btn-success">Go to step 2</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="2">
        <p>This is step 2</p>
        <button ng-click="setStep(3)" class="btn btn-success">Go to step 3</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="3">
        <p>This is step 3</p>
        <button ng-click="setStep(1)" class="btn btn-success">Back to start</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in you controller :

```
$scope.step = 1;
$scope.setStep = function (num) {
    $scope.step = num;
};
```

You can check the result here : http://jsfiddle.net/Gg92r/

Comment: Richard - you should accept the question if you found that it solved your answer

Comment: and if there are 100 quuestions...you propose only using angular to manually enter all that html and text? No point using angular then and no way to simply add/remove a question using any data storage methods

Comment: I actually think @charlietfl's solution (in the comments on the question) is a better one.